Paragraphs in regexps that are not defined in the minibuffer
I sometimes have epubs that I prefer reading in org-mode, so I convert them into text files and format them while reading. That leaves all the footnotes as bare numbers, so I used replace-regexp to make them into footnotes, and wanted to define a command based on that for future uses:
(defun ahp/formatfns ()
  "This command formats numbers at the beginning of a line into footnotes."
  (interactive)
  (replace-regexp "^J\([0-9]*\)" "^J[fn:\1]"))

Here, the strings were copypasted from the command I used (which worked), so the ^J's were not written from two signs but inserted from the replace history and function as one sign in the buffer. Yet, when I use this command, it matches zero expressions in the text I've used the replace-regexp on, reset using undo to its prior state. I've also tried to simply insert paragraphs into the replace strings instead of the ^J's, but that didn't match either. Why is that? And how can I define the command correctly?

Does this answer your question? re-search-forward Regex behavior for OR boolean

Your problem isn't the ^J character.  Your problem is that you're not escaping your backslashes.
(However, to avoid confusion, I'm replacing your ^J with the escape sequence for a newline recognised by the double-quoted read syntax for strings, which is "\n".)

(replace-regexp "\n\([0-9]*\)" "\n[fn:\1]"))


In the double-quoted read syntax for strings "\(" and "\)" are the same as "(" and ")" (i.e. there's no point in escaping them).  A backslash \ is special, however (being the escaping character), and so if you want to put a literal backslash into a double-quoted string you need to escape it with another backslash.
I.e. To write the regexp \([0-9]*\) as a double-quoted string you need to escape the backslashes:
(replace-regexp "\n\\([0-9]*\\)" "\n[fn:\\1]"))

See also re-search-forward Regex behavior for OR boolean along with the numerous Q&As linked from there.
